# Match people into groups according to food preference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I am looking for an algorithm which helps me to distribute people into 3 groups (a, b , c). The people in a group should fit together, which means that the food preferences should match in a way that they all can agree to the same kind of food.  Each cluster (sub-group) within the group consists of 6 people.
Let's say there are 4 types of food preferences:

1. The person likes to eat meat
2. The person likes to eat vegetarian food
3. The person likes to eat vegan food
4. The person has no food preferences, which means the person basically likes to eat everything

I want to distribute the people into 3 logical groups:

- Group a: meat and no_food_preference
- Group b: vegan, vegetarian and no_food_preference
- Group c: vegetarian  and no_food_preference

I use the people with no_food_preference to fill up the cluster in order to make sure that each cluster contains 6 people.

After distributing  all people into groups, each group will consist of multiple of 6 people.

**My problem:** I tried very hard, but I can not find an algorithm which does this for me. I find it very hard to handle the fact, that the algorithm should handle any number of participants.

**Example:**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
 {
 "user_id": [i for i in range(1, 55)],    
 "Master_FoodPreference": ["meat", "vegetarian", "meat", "vegan", "meat", "vegetarian", "meat", "vegetarian", "no_food_preference", 
                           "meat",'no_food_preference', 'vegetarian',"meat", "meat",
                           "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegan", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "no_food_preference", "vegan", 
                           "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian",
                           "meat", "vegetarian", "meat", "vegetarian", "no_food_preference", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", 
                           "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "no_food_preference", 
                           "no_food_preference", "no_food_preference", "meat", "no_food_preference", "meat", "meat", 
                           "vegan", "no_food_preference", "no_food_preference", "vegan" ,"no_food_preference" ,"vegan" ,"vegan" ]
 }
)

df.head() 
>>>>
  user_id   Master_FoodPreference
0   1       meat
1   2       vegetarian
2   3       meat
3   4       vegan
4   5       meat
```

How would you group these people into `group_a`, `group_b` and `group_c`?

**EDIT - Group Composition**:
Each group (a,b,c) will get a specific label:

- Group a: People will cook a meal with meat
- Group b: People will cook a meal which is vegan
- Group c: People will cook a meal which is vegetarian

This means, we should try to bring most vegeterians into `group_c`. If `group_c` is complete, we put them into `group_b`. Note: we can not put vegans into `group_c`, because vegans don't eat vegy-food.

Comment: I know this is not a typical stackoverflow question since the question is not very specific. Maybe you know any other forums where I can get help with my problem?!

Comment: Your last phrase is not clear about vegetarians. The priority is to fit into group B or C?

Comment: Very sorry for the confusions!!! I edited my notes again. I hope now it makes sence for you?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not seem too difficult: classify the items in groups, then use items from "no_food_preference" to fill the other groups modulo 6 - and if some items still remain in "no_food_preference" move them in another group:

```
pref = ["meat", "vegetarian", "meat", "vegan", "meat", "vegetarian", "meat", "vegetarian", "no_food_preference", 
                           "meat",'no_food_preference', 'vegetarian',"meat", "meat",
                           "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegan", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "no_food_preference", "vegan", 
                           "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian",
                           "meat", "vegetarian", "meat", "vegetarian", "no_food_preference", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", 
                           "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "no_food_preference", 
                           "no_food_preference", "no_food_preference", "meat", "no_food_preference", "meat", "meat", 
                           "vegan", "no_food_preference", "no_food_preference", "vegan" ,"no_food_preference" ,"vegan" ,"vegan" ]

def assign_groups(pref):
    groups={}
    for i,p in enumerate(pref):
        if p in groups:
            groups[p].append(i)
        else:
            groups[p] = [i]
        for p in ['meat','vegetarian','vegan']:
            need = len(groups[p]) % 6
            if need:
                for i in range(6-need):
                    groups[p].append(groups["no_food_preference"].pop())
        if len(groups["no_food_preference"]):
            groups["meat"] += groups["no_food_preference"]
            del groups["no_food_preference"]
        return groups

assign_groups(pref)       
{'meat': [0, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 13, 27, 29, 43, 45, 46, 8, 10, 19, 31, 40, 41], 'vegetarian': [1, 5, 7, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39], 'vegan': [3, 16, 20, 47, 50, 52, 53, 51, 49, 48, 44, 42]}
```

This will work if the total number of items is a multiple of 6, of course.

**EDIT**

I updated the code to be more compliant to the original request, and to handle some special cases. Some observations:

- We need the total number of people to be a multiple of 6 (or of the value we choose for the "cluster" size)
- If we want to be sure to handle *all* possibilities we need to assume that the meat-eaters can also eat vegetables - i.e they can be used to fill a veggie or even a vegan cluster. Otherwise some cases are unsolvable, e.g., if cluster size is 6, then 7 x meat, 7 x veggie, 7 x vegan, 3 x no-pref has no solutions
- So we deal with the vegan group first, filling it with no-prefs, then if needed with vegetarians, then if still needed with meat-eaters; then deal with the remaining vegetarians, filling their group with no-prefs then meat-eaters; and lastly with the meat group, which can only be filled with no-prefs; at the end, if some no-pref clusters remain, we add them to one group (meat)

The modified code looks like this (I added a helper function to move people from a group to another):

```
pref = ["meat", "vegetarian", "meat", "vegan", "meat", "vegetarian", "meat", "vegetarian", "no_food_preference", "meat",
        'no_food_preference', 'vegetarian',"meat", "meat","vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegan", "vegetarian", "vegetarian",
        "no_food_preference", "vegan", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian",
        "meat", "vegetarian", "meat", "vegetarian", "no_food_preference", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian",
        "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "vegetarian", "no_food_preference",
        "no_food_preference", "no_food_preference", "meat", "no_food_preference", "meat", "meat", "vegan",
        "no_food_preference", "no_food_preference", "vegan" ,"no_food_preference" ,"vegan" ,"vegan" ]

groups = {}

def assign_groups(pref, pergroup):
    global groups, pref
    groups = {'meat':[], 'vegetarian':[], 'vegan':[], 'no_food_preference':[]}
    fillers = {'meat':['no_food_preference'],
               'vegetarian':['no_food_preference', 'meat'],
               'vegan':['no_food_preference', 'vegetarian', 'meat']}
    for i,p in enumerate(pref):
        groups[p].append(i)
    for p in ['vegan','vegetarian','meat']:
        need = len(groups[p]) % pergroup
        if need:
            fill_idx = 0
            need = pergroup - need
            while need:
                f = fillers[p][fill_idx]
                avail = len(groups[f])
                if need > avail:
                    from_to(p, f, avail)
                    need -= avail
                    fill_idx += 1
                else:
                    from_to(p, f, need)
                    need = 0
    
    if len(groups["no_food_preference"]):
        from_to("meat", "no_food_preference", len(groups["no_food_preference"]))
    return groups

def from_to(p,f,n):
    global groups
    for i in range(n):
        groups[p].append(groups[f].pop())

assign_groups(pref, 6)
{'meat': [0, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 13, 27, 29, 43, 45, 46, 41, 40, 31, 19, 10, 8], 'vegetarian': [1, 5, 7, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39], 'vegan': [3, 16, 20, 47, 50, 52, 53, 51, 49, 48, 44, 42], 'no_food_preference': []}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This looks very promissing! I tried to run the code, but ``assign_groups`` gives an error in line ``groups[p].append(groups["no_food_preference"].pop())``. It says ``KeyError: 'no_food_preference``. Is it just me or do you have a bug in the code?

Comment: I run it, and it worked for me. It would seem there are no people with "no_food_preference", and there is at least one group that needs to add someone to reach a multiple of 6. Did you try with your original example?

Comment: I just realized I didn't see you wanted to put vegans and vegetarians together in group B. I assume this means that a vegetarian can be placed indifferently in group B or C?

Comment: Yes, a vegeterian can be put into a group of vegan people (``group_b``). But you can not put a vegan person into a group of vegetarian (``group_c``).  I think sometimes it is not possible, but the goal is to make most of the people happy with the food-group

Comment: I would love to run the code and see what it does. Therefore I copy pasted it into [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aEemWc0QHaYFrZFRcDTPXRN6tMm3iBnE?usp=sharing). Sorry, maybe it's obvious, but what is ``pergroup``? I need it to as input for ``assign_groups``. Maybe you like to add it to your example?

Comment: Sorry, I omitted to say that I just added that variable to have the possibility to experiment with different cluster sizes. For your example just pass 6. I will edit the answer adding the function call

Comment: Awesome. Looks great at the first glance. I will have a closer look at the weekend. I will come back to you! For now, thank you so much!

Comment: Code works perfect for given example! Thx so much! Is ``pergroup`` the only parameter which I have to change in order to change group size from 6 to some other number, e.g. 3?

Comment: Talking about limitations: You mentioned some of them in your post. Most common problem is that we do not have many participants AND food_preferences can become a problem when distributing people. Example: In case we have 3 x ``meat``, 2 x ``vegeterian`` and 1 x ``vegan``. How do you deal with it? I suppose you decrease ``pergroup`` from 6 to 3. But then code runs forever.

Comment: Very sorry for being so picky. It's is extremly important that the algorithm can handle each kind of combination. Your help is very much appreciated and will hopefully make many participants happy (it's a school project)!

Comment: Yes, `pergroup` is the only parameter to change. And I expect that 3x meat, 2x vegetarian and 1x vegan should result in 1 vegan group (so the lone vegan would ruin the dinner for everybody else :D ). I'm going to test it later

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, one vegan person ruins the fun of everybody else :) Unfortunately this is a very realistic combination. Especially at the beginning we expect only a few participants. This is where the current algorithm may run into trouble, as shown in the example above.

Comment: Yes, there were one error and one inaccuracy in the code: I forgot to update `fill_idx` so when you needed to take people from more than one group the code would loop forever; and `groups` was initialized outside the function so if you wanted to call it twice you got weird results. Editing the answer, now it should work

Comment: As far as I can see the code can handle every combination and works perfect. Thank you very much for your great help. This part was crucial I couldn't done it without your help! Note: I had to remove ``pref`` as a global variable inside ``assign_groups``. If not I get: ``SyntaxError: name 'pref' is parameter and global``.

Comment: Well, I don't know where that global `pref` came from... I don't have it in my file, so I must have messed things up while copying it. One small further improvement would be to remove `global`s at all, for example creating a class and transforming `groups`, and perhaps also `pref` and `pergroup`, into instance variables

Answer (score 0):

Create 4 dataframes: 3 for your groups (dfA, dfB, dfC) and 1 for the group with no food preference (dfX), then fill each group A, B, C inplace with group X if needed:

```
dfX = df[df['Master_FoodPreference'].eq('no_food_preference')]

dfA = df[df['Master_FoodPreference'].eq('meat')]
dfA = dfA.append(dfX.sample(len(dfA) % 6))

dfB = df[df['Master_FoodPreference'].eq('vegan')
         | df['Master_FoodPreference'].eq('vegetarian')]
dfB = dfB.append(dfX.sample(len(dfB) % 6))

dfC = df[df['Master_FoodPreference'].eq('vegetarian')]
dfC = dfC.append(dfX.sample(len(dfC) % 6))
```

Output:

```
>>> dfB
    user_id Master_FoodPreference
1         2            vegetarian
3         4                 vegan
5         6            vegetarian
7         8            vegetarian
11       12            vegetarian
14       15            vegetarian
15       16            vegetarian
16       17                 vegan
17       18            vegetarian
18       19            vegetarian
20       21                 vegan
21       22            vegetarian
22       23            vegetarian
23       24            vegetarian
24       25            vegetarian
25       26            vegetarian
26       27            vegetarian
28       29            vegetarian
30       31            vegetarian
32       33            vegetarian
33       34            vegetarian
34       35            vegetarian
35       36            vegetarian
36       37            vegetarian
37       38            vegetarian
38       39            vegetarian
39       40            vegetarian
47       48                 vegan
50       51                 vegan
52       53                 vegan
53       54                 vegan
49       50    no_food_preference
```

> After distributing all people into groups, each group will consist of multiple of 6 people.

It's possible with your sample:

```
# Before append
>>> len(dfA), len(dfB), len(dfC), len(dfX)
(12, 31, 24, 11)
```

Comment: Wow, this is a very short solution. I like it.  One question: Whats ``dfX``? Can you please specify this, so that I can run the code for myself? Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Sorry, bad copy/paste, I forgot `dfX`. I updated my answer.

Comment: I like your solution, but I have some comments: 1) I think I was not clear with the composition of the  groups. I will add a note to the main post! 2) At the end I need 3 groups and maybe a 4th group for all people who did not find a group. Can we therefore distribute people from ``dfX`` to the other groups?

Comment: I added some comments to my main post. I think the distribution in your example can be optimised according to my comment.